# How to estimate confidence-intervals beyond the current simulated step, based on existing data for 1,000,000 monte-carlo simulations?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, curve-fitting

Situation:

1. I have a program which generates 600 random numbers per "step".
2. These 600 numbers are fed into a complicated algorithm, which then outputs a single value (which can be positive or negative) for that "step"; let's call this Value-X for that step.
3. This Value-X is then added to a Global-Value-Y, making the latter a running sum of each step in the series.
4. I have essentially run this simulation 1,000,000 times, recording the values of Global-Value-Y at each step in those simulations.
5. I have "calculated confidence intervals" from those one-million simulations, by sorting the simulations by (the absolute value of) their Global-Value-Y at each column, and finding the 90th percentile, the 99th percentile, etc.

What I want to do:

- Using the pool of simulation results, "extrapolate" from that to find some equation that will estimate the confidence intervals for results from the used algorithm, many "steps" into the future, without having to extend the runs of those one-million simulations further. (it would take too long to keep running those one-million simulations indefinitely)

Note that the results do not have to be *terribly* precise at this point; the results are mainly used atm as a visual indicator on the graph, for the user to get an idea of how "normal" the current simulation's results are relative to the confidence-intervals extrapolated from the historical data of the one-million simulations.

Anyway, I've already made some attempts at finding an "estimated curve-fit" of the confidence-intervals from the historical data (ie. those based on the one-million simulations), but the results are not quite precise enough.

Here are the key parts from the curve-fitting Python code I've tried: (link to [full code here](https://gist.github.com/Venryx/74a44ed25d5c4dc7768d13e22b36c8a4))

```py
# curve fit functions

def func_linear(t, a, b):
    return a*t +b

def func_quadratic(t, a, b, c):
    return a*pow(t,2) + b*t +c

def func_cubic(t, a, b, c, d):
    return a*pow(t,3) + b*pow(t,2) + c*t + d

def func_biquadratic(t, a, b, c, d, e):
    return a*pow(t,4) + b*pow(t,3) + c*pow(t,2) + d*t + e

[...]

import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# calling the read function on the recorded percentile/confidence-intervals data
xVals,yVals = read_file()

# using inbuilt function for linear fit
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_linear, xVals, yVals)
fit_linear = func_linear(np.array(xVals), *popt)

[same here for the other curve-fit functions]

[...]

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (40,20)

# plotting the respective curve fits 
plt.plot(xVals, yVals, color="blue", linewidth=3)
plt.plot(xVals, fit_linear, color="red", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xVals, fit_quadratic, color="green", linewidth=2)
plt.plot(xVals, fit_cubic, color="orange", linewidth=2)
#plt.plot(xVals, fit_biquadratic, color="black", linewidth=2) # extremely off
plt.legend(['Actual data','linear','quadratic','cubic','biquadratic'])
plt.xlabel('Session Column')
plt.ylabel('y-value for CI')
plt.title('Curve fitting')
plt.show()
```

And here are the results: (with the purple "actual data" being the 99.9th percentile of the Global-Value-Ys at each step, from the one-million recorded simulations)
[image]

While it seems to be attempting to estimate a curve-fit (over the graphed ~630 steps), the results are not quite accurate enough for my purposes. The imprecision is particularly noticeable at the first ~5% of the graph, where the estimate-curve is far too high. (though practically, my issues are more on the other end, as the CI curve-fit keeps getting less accurate the farther out from the historical data it goes)

**EDIT**: As requested by a commenter, here is a GitHub gist of the Python code I'm using to attempt the curve-fit (and it includes the data used): https://gist.github.com/Venryx/74a44ed25d5c4dc7768d13e22b36c8a4

So my questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my usage of scypy's `curve_fit` function?
2. Or is the `curve_fit` function too basic of a tool to get meaningful estimates/extrapolations of confidence-intervals for random-walk data like this?
3. If so, is there some alternative that works better for estimating/extrapolating confidence-intervals from random-walk data of this sort?

Comment: Your post is detailed and includes a lot of questions while it should focus on a single one and miss important parts. It is impossible to tell if your fitting procedure is problematic without having the dataset as the MSE surface to find the minimum does depend on it. You seem to doubt of the fitting procedure but what is the output you are expecting? Could you detail how you think your CI is related to your fits?

Comment: @jlandercy I have added a link to the GitHub gist showing my attempted curve-fit code: https://gist.github.com/Venryx/74a44ed25d5c4dc7768d13e22b36c8a4

Comment: > "without having the dataset as the MSE surface to find the minimum does depend on it" I have updated the gist to include the raw recorded confidence-intervals data (which my code is attempting to curve-fit to), if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: > "You seem to doubt of the fitting procedure but what is the output you are expecting? Could you detail how you think your CI is related to your fits?" I was expecting a curve that more closely matched that purple line of the "actual data" (ie. the precise values of the 99.9th percentile/confidence-interval derived from the one million simulations). So I'm asking whether I'm doing something wrong with the curve-fitting; and if not, what alternative there is for making estimates/extrapolations of this sort.

Comment: I have found a model that reasonably fits your data, let me know if it address you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understand your question, you have a lot of Monte Carlo simulations gathered as (x,y) points and you want to find a model that reasonably fits them.

Importing your data to create a MCVE:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([
    [0,77],[1,101],[2,121],[3,138],[4,151],[5,165],[6,178],[7,189],[8,200],[9,210],[10,221],[11,229],[12,238],[13,247],[14,254],[15,264],[16,271],[17,278],[18,285],[19,291],[20,299],[21,305],[22,312],[23,318],[24,326],[25,331],[26,338],[27,344],[28,350],[29,356],[30,362],[31,365],[32,371],[33,376],[34,383],[35,387],[36,393],[37,399],[38,404],[39,409],[40,414],[41,419],[42,425],[43,430],[44,435],[45,439],[46,444],[47,447],[48,453],[49,457],[50,461],[51,467],[52,472],[53,476],[54,480],[55,483],[56,488],[57,491],[58,495],[59,499],[60,504],[61,508],[62,512],[63,516],[64,521],[65,525],[66,528],[67,532],[68,536],[69,540],[70,544],[71,547],[72,551],[73,554],[74,560],[75,563],[76,567],[77,571],[78,574],[79,577],[80,582],[81,585],[82,588],[83,591],[84,595],[85,600],[86,603],[87,605],[88,610],[89,613],[90,617],[91,621],[92,624],[93,627],[94,630],[95,632],[96,636],[97,638],[98,642],[99,645],[100,649],[101,653],[102,656],[103,660],[104,664],[105,667],[106,670],[107,673],[108,674],[109,679],[110,681],[111,684],[112,687],[113,689],[114,692],[115,697],[116,698],[117,701],[118,705],[119,708],[120,710],[121,712],[122,716],[123,718],[124,722],[125,725],[126,728],[127,730],[128,732],[129,735],[130,739],[131,742],[132,743],[133,747],[134,751],[135,753],[136,754],[137,757],[138,760],[139,762],[140,765],[141,768],[142,769],[143,774],[144,775],[145,778],[146,782],[147,784],[148,788],[149,790],[150,793],[151,795],[152,799],[153,801],[154,804],[155,808],[156,811],[157,812],[158,814],[159,816],[160,819],[161,820],[162,824],[163,825],[164,828],[165,830],[166,832],[167,834],[168,836],[169,839],[170,843],[171,845],[172,847],[173,850],[174,853],[175,856],[176,858],[177,859],[178,863],[179,865],[180,869],[181,871],[182,873],[183,875],[184,878],[185,880],[186,883],[187,884],[188,886],[189,887],[190,892],[191,894],[192,895],[193,898],[194,900],[195,903],[196,903],[197,905],[198,907],[199,910],[200,911],[201,914],[202,919],[203,921],[204,922],[205,926],[206,927],[207,928],[208,931],[209,933],[210,935],[211,940],[212,942],[213,944],[214,943],[215,948],[216,950],[217,954],[218,955],[219,957],[220,959],[221,963],[222,965],[223,967],[224,969],[225,970],[226,971],[227,973],[228,975],[229,979],[230,980],[231,982],[232,983],[233,986],[234,988],[235,990],[236,992],[237,993],[238,996],[239,998],[240,1001],[241,1003],[242,1007],[243,1007],[244,1011],[245,1012],[246,1013],[247,1016],[248,1019],[249,1019],[250,1020],[251,1024],[252,1027],[253,1029],[254,1028],[255,1031],[256,1033],[257,1035],[258,1038],[259,1040],[260,1041],[261,1046],[262,1046],[263,1046],[264,1048],[265,1052],[266,1053],[267,1055],[268,1056],[269,1057],[270,1059],[271,1061],[272,1064],[273,1067],[274,1065],[275,1068],[276,1071],[277,1073],[278,1074],[279,1075],[280,1080],[281,1081],[282,1083],[283,1084],[284,1085],[285,1086],[286,1088],[287,1090],[288,1092],[289,1095],[290,1097],[291,1100],[292,1100],[293,1102],[294,1104],[295,1107],[296,1109],[297,1110],[298,1113],[299,1114],[300,1112],[301,1116],[302,1118],[303,1120],[304,1121],[305,1124],[306,1124],[307,1126],[308,1126],[309,1130],[310,1131],[311,1131],[312,1135],[313,1137],[314,1138],[315,1141],[316,1145],[317,1147],[318,1147],[319,1148],[320,1152],[321,1151],[322,1152],[323,1155],[324,1157],[325,1158],[326,1161],[327,1161],[328,1163],[329,1164],[330,1167],[331,1169],[332,1172],[333,1175],[334,1177],[335,1177],[336,1179],[337,1181],[338,1180],[339,1184],[340,1186],[341,1186],[342,1188],[343,1190],[344,1193],[345,1195],[346,1197],[347,1198],[348,1198],[349,1200],[350,1203],[351,1204],[352,1206],[353,1207],[354,1209],[355,1210],[356,1210],[357,1214],[358,1215],[359,1215],[360,1219],[361,1221],[362,1222],[363,1223],[364,1224],[365,1225],[366,1228],[367,1232],[368,1233],[369,1236],[370,1237],[371,1239],[372,1239],[373,1243],[374,1244],[375,1244],[376,1244],[377,1247],[378,1249],[379,1251],[380,1251],[381,1254],[382,1256],[383,1260],[384,1259],[385,1260],[386,1263],[387,1264],[388,1265],[389,1267],[390,1271],[391,1271],[392,1273],[393,1274],[394,1277],[395,1278],[396,1279],[397,1281],[398,1285],[399,1286],[400,1289],[401,1288],[402,1290],[403,1290],[404,1291],[405,1292],[406,1295],[407,1297],[408,1298],[409,1301],[410,1300],[411,1301],[412,1303],[413,1305],[414,1307],[415,1311],[416,1312],[417,1313],[418,1314],[419,1316],[420,1317],[421,1316],[422,1319],[423,1319],[424,1321],[425,1322],[426,1323],[427,1325],[428,1326],[429,1329],[430,1328],[431,1330],[432,1334],[433,1335],[434,1338],[435,1340],[436,1342],[437,1342],[438,1344],[439,1346],[440,1347],[441,1347],[442,1349],[443,1351],[444,1352],[445,1355],[446,1358],[447,1356],[448,1359],[449,1362],[450,1362],[451,1366],[452,1365],[453,1367],[454,1368],[455,1368],[456,1368],[457,1371],[458,1371],[459,1374],[460,1374],[461,1377],[462,1379],[463,1382],[464,1384],[465,1387],[466,1388],[467,1386],[468,1390],[469,1391],[470,1396],[471,1395],[472,1396],[473,1399],[474,1400],[475,1403],[476,1403],[477,1406],[478,1406],[479,1412],[480,1409],[481,1410],[482,1413],[483,1413],[484,1418],[485,1418],[486,1422],[487,1422],[488,1423],[489,1424],[490,1426],[491,1426],[492,1430],[493,1430],[494,1431],[495,1433],[496,1435],[497,1437],[498,1439],[499,1440],[500,1442],[501,1443],[502,1442],[503,1444],[504,1447],[505,1448],[506,1448],[507,1450],[508,1454],[509,1455],[510,1456],[511,1460],[512,1459],[513,1460],[514,1464],[515,1464],[516,1466],[517,1467],[518,1469],[519,1470],[520,1471],[521,1475],[522,1477],[523,1476],[524,1478],[525,1480],[526,1480],[527,1479],[528,1480],[529,1483],[530,1484],[531,1485],[532,1486],[533,1487],[534,1489],[535,1489],[536,1489],[537,1492],[538,1492],[539,1494],[540,1493],[541,1494],[542,1496],[543,1497],[544,1499],[545,1500],[546,1501],[547,1504],[548,1506],[549,1508],[550,1507],[551,1509],[552,1510],[553,1510],[554,1512],[555,1513],[556,1516],[557,1519],[558,1520],[559,1520],[560,1522],[561,1525],[562,1527],[563,1530],[564,1531],[565,1533],[566,1533],[567,1534],[568,1538],[569,1539],[570,1538],[571,1540],[572,1541],[573,1543],[574,1545],[575,1545],[576,1547],[577,1549],[578,1550],[579,1554],[580,1554],[581,1557],[582,1559],[583,1564],[584,1565],[585,1567],[586,1567],[587,1568],[588,1570],[589,1571],[590,1569],[591,1572],[592,1572],[593,1574],[594,1574],[595,1574],[596,1579],[597,1578],[598,1579],[599,1582],[600,1583],[601,1583],[602,1586],[603,1585],[604,1588],[605,1590],[606,1592],[607,1596],[608,1595],[609,1596],[610,1598],[611,1601],[612,1603],[613,1604],[614,1605],[615,1605],[616,1608],[617,1611],[618,1613],[619,1615],[620,1613],[621,1616],[622,1617],[623,1617],[624,1619],[625,1617],[626,1618],[627,1619],[628,1618],[629,1621],[630,1624],[631,1626],[632,1626],[633,1631]
])
```

And plotting them show a curve that seems to have a square root and linear behaviors respectively at the beginning and the end of the dataset. So let's try this first simple model:

```
def model(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.sqrt(x) + b*x + c
```

Notice than formulated as this, it is a LLS problem which is a good point for solving it. The optimization with `curve_fit` works as expected:

```
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, data[:,0],  data[:,1])

# [61.20233162  0.08897784 27.76102519]

# [[ 1.51146696e-02 -4.81216428e-04 -1.01108383e-01]
#  [-4.81216428e-04  1.59734405e-05  3.01250722e-03]
#  [-1.01108383e-01  3.01250722e-03  7.63590271e-01]]
```

And returns a pretty decent adjustment. Graphically it looks like:

[image]

Of course this is just an adjustment to an arbitrary model chosen based on a personal experience (to me it looks like a specific heterogeneous reaction kinetics).

If you have a theoretical reason to accept or reject this model then you should use it to discriminate. I would also investigate units of parameters to check if they have significant meanings.

But in any case this is out of scope of the Stack Overflow community which is oriented to solve programming issues not scientific validation of models (see Cross Validated or Math Overflow if you want to dig deeper). If you do so, draw my attention on it, I would be glad to follow this question in details.

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks great; given the closeness of the match, and the simplicity of the function, it seems to me you nailed the right model. I don't have the background in math/statistics to confirm this, but I'm very happy with the results you've shown (which I've since replicated), and it is well within the margin of error I need for my use-case. This is exactly the sort of "quick solution based on past experience" I was hoping for by posting my question, and I consider it solved. :)

Comment: @Venryx you are welcome, do you mind mark it as answered if yout hink it is solved. cheers.